# The method '[]' was called on null: firebase flutter

Tags: flutter, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-authentication, builder

I need to retrieve User Data from Firebase and use a builder to pass on the data to UI.  When I run the apps, I method is called in on Null.

I tried many ways to call firebase data but I keep receive error message on provider or on calling the data NULL.

The error is most likely coming from the method _getProfileData() below.

```
  _getProfileData(AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
      final uid = await Provider.of(context, listen: false).authNotifier.getCurrentUID();
    await Provider.of(context, listen: false)
        .collection('Users')
        .document(uid)
        .get().then((result) {
          user.isAdmin = result.data['isAdmin'];
    });
  }
```

When I made the changes below by using Provider, another error appears with Provider not working.

```
final uid = await Provider.of<authNotifier>(context, listen: false).getCurrentUID();
```

I placed the getter in the API.

```
  final FirebaseAuth _firebaseAuth = FirebaseAuth.instance;

  // GET UID
  Future<String> getCurrentUID(User user, AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
    return (await _firebaseAuth.currentUser()).uid;
  }

  // GET CURRENT USER
  Future getCurrentUser(User user, AuthNotifier authNotifier) async {
    return await _firebaseAuth.currentUser();
  }
  Stream<String> get onAuthStateChanged => auth.onAuthStateChanged.map(
        (FirebaseUser user) => user?.uid,
      );
```

I structured User Data as below.

```
class User {
  List favorites = [];  
  String documentID;
  String displayName;
  String email;
  String password;
  bool isAdmin;

  User({
    this.favorites,
    this.documentID,
    this.displayName, 
    this.email,
    this.password,
    this.isAdmin,
    });

  factory User.fromFirestore(DocumentSnapshot document) {
    Map data = document.data;

    return User(
      favorites: data['favorite'] ?? [],
      documentID: document.documentID,
      displayName: data['displayName'] ?? '',
      email: data['email'] ?? '',
      isAdmin: data['isAdmin'] ?? false,
    );
  }

  // get admin => null;
    Map<String, dynamic> toMap() {
    return {
      'displayName': displayName,
      'email': email,
      'isAdmin': isAdmin,
    };
}
}
```

Comment: On the return method you have that if "data[''favorite']" is null return instead "[]" and empty array, however firestore is not able to process empty arrays, try modifing this to return somehting else.

Comment: Thanks Louis, what about the admin string.. the method is failing to retrieve data from firebase.

Comment: Could yo please try `Map data = document.data.data;` insted of `Map data = document.data;`.
Also as the previous comment, watch out for the empty array, could cause some issues.